# Select element of a CollectionView with groups

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `CollectionView` with groups, and I would like to be able to select the single element within the `Observablecollection` which contains all my objects of the `IconDiary` class

```
    public class IconDiary
            {
                public string isSource;
            }
    
     public class IconGroup : ObservableCollection<IconDiary>
            {
                public string Name { get; private set; }
    
                public IconGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<IconDiary> icon) : base(icon)
                {
                    Name = name;
                }
            }
    
            public ObservableCollection<IconGroup> TotIcon { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<IconGroup>();
            private void AddActivity_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TotIcon.Add(new IconGroup("Cibo", new ObservableCollection<IconDiary>
                {
                    new IconDiary { isSource = "IC001" },
                }));
                ColTotIcon.ItemsSource = TotIcon;
            }
```

This is the button where the user selects the item, but this is not good because the `TotIcon` `ObservableCollection` is of type `IconGroup` and not `IconDiary`, and the `isSource` property does not exist in this context

```
     IconDiary ic;
            private void SelectIconActivity_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ic = new IconDiary();
                var button = sender as Button;
                var model = button.BindingContext as IconDiary;
                ic = TotIcon.FirstOrDefault(X => X.isSource == model.isSource);
            }
```

**XAML**

```
<CollectionView 
                        x:Name="ColTotIcon" 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                        Margin="10"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        IsGrouped="True">
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="8" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="9"/>
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                                    <Label 
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                                        TextColor="Black"
                                        FontSize="15">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding isSource}"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="SelectIconActivity_Clicked" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: use `SelectMany`

Comment: I can't use it very well

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a CollectionView with groups, and I would like to be able to select the single element within the Observablecollection which contains all my objects of the IconDiary class

From your description, you want to select one item(IconDiary) from CollectionView, if yes, I suggest you can get selected item by SelectionChanged event.

```
 <CollectionView
            IsGrouped="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Icons}"
            SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding isSource}" />
                      
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label
                        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="Large"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

           
        </CollectionView>
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new GroupIconsViewModel();
    }  
 
    private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IconDiary selectedIcon = e.CurrentSelection[0] as IconDiary;
    }
}

public class IconDiary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string isSource { get; set; }
}

public class IconGroup : ObservableCollection<IconDiary>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IconGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<IconDiary> icon) : base(icon)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
  
}

public class GroupIconsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<IconGroup> Icons { get; set; }
    public GroupIconsViewModel()
    {
        Icons = new ObservableCollection<IconGroup>();
        Icons.Add(new IconGroup("aaa",new ObservableCollection<IconDiary>() { new IconDiary { isSource="001",Name="a 123"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="002",Name="a 234"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="003",Name="a 456"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="004",Name="a 567"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="005",Name="a 678"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="006",Name="a 890"}

        }));
        Icons.Add(new IconGroup("bbb", new ObservableCollection<IconDiary>() { new IconDiary { isSource="01",Name="b 12"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="02",Name="b 23"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="03",Name="b 34"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="04",Name="b 45"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="05",Name="b 56"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="06",Name="b 67"}

        }));
        Icons.Add(new IconGroup("ccc", new ObservableCollection<IconDiary>() { new IconDiary { isSource="1",Name="c 1"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="2",Name="c 1"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="3",Name="c 1"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="4",Name="c 1"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="5",Name="c 1"},
        new IconDiary { isSource="6",Name="c 1"}

        }));
    }
}
```

But you said that user select item bu button click, where is your button, you put button in CollectionView DataTemplate? If yes, you can also get current selected item by button.BindingContex.

```
 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding isSource}" />
                        <Button
                            x:Name="btn"
                            Clicked="btn_Clicked"
                            Text="select items" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

 private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var model = button.BindingContext as IconDiary;
    }
```